# Question about TKSheets

Tags: linux, python, gui

I have a TKSheet that I have created with a list of running processes on my Linux computer. I am trying to enable row selection of the sheet so that items can be selected and then interacted with. Below is the code that I have tried after reading the TKSheets documentation, but it still doesn't seem to be working, and I believe the error is something small. This should be set by the line prcsht.set_sheet_data.

````
    procsht.grid(padx = GlobalVars.defpadx, pady = GlobalVars.defpady)
    procsht.enable_bindings(("right_click_popup_menu", "row_select"))
    procsht.set_sheet_data(data=GlobalVars.proclist)
    procsht.headers(["User","PID","CPU %","Mem %","TTY","Command"])
    proctabbtnfrm = tk.Frame(proctab)```
````